# beginner java recursion test

Tags: java, recursion

can anyone explain to me how the output was given?

```
  public static void recursionTest(int num){

   if(num>0){

       recursionTest(num - 1);
        System.out.println("Inside the base case: "+num);

   }

   System.out.println("Outside the base case: "+num);

}
```

input 5
output
Outside the base case: 0

Inside the base case: 1

Outside the base case: 1

Inside the base case: 2

Outside the base case: 2

Inside the base case: 3

Outside the base case: 3

Inside the base case: 4

Outside the base case: 4

Inside the base case: 5

Outside the base case: 5

Answer (score 0):

I would change your code slightly:

```
public static void recursionTest(int num) {
    if (num > 0) {
        recursionTest(num - 1);
        System.out.println("Inside the inductive case: " + num);
        // make sure to return here so that the base case message
        // does not accidentally get printed
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("Inside the base case: " + num);
}
```

This outputs the following:

```
Inside the base case: 0
Inside the inductive case: 1
Inside the inductive case: 2
Inside the inductive case: 3
Inside the inductive case: 4
Inside the inductive case: 5
```

The *base* case of a recursion is the case which *ends* that recursion.  In your case, the base case occurs when the number reaches zero, and we do not make further recursive calls.  Otherwise, we keep making recursive calls, passing the input number decremented by one.

The reason the output appears to be backwards is that the first print statement we actually hit is the base case.  We only print the inductive statements on the way out from the recursion.

### Demo

Comment: thanks for the info, but i'm just wondering how the output was given, because for me i'm expecting a different output

Comment: @JoselParayno I updated my answer with more information.

Answer (score 0):

As we know java recursion uses stack to execute programs.
whenever you are dealing with recursion best way is to imagine a stack and put your data execution (method calls) inside stack and go step by step...

in your case if your input is 5...

```
stack would be -> 5 -> recursive call { recursionTest(4); print(inside=5); print(outside=5;) }
stack would be -> 4 -> recursive call { recursionTest(3) print(inside=4); print(outside=4;) }
stack would be -> 3 -> recursive call { recursionTest(2) print(inside=3); print(outside=3;) }
stack would be -> 2 -> recursive call { recursionTest(1) print(inside=2); print(outside=2;) }
stack would be -> 1 -> recursive call { recursionTest(0) print(inside=1); print(outside=1;) }

finally recursion(0)...
```

when number is 0 it goes out of if and prints first line which is

```
Outside the base case: 0
```

then it runs in reverse order since method calls got stacked (LIFO) which is bottom up from 1 to 5 as 1 was last input in stack and 5 was last element is stack...

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You have used an unusual form for the recursion. It's best to stick to a standard, consistent form so that you will always know what to expect when you read the code.

The standard form for a recursive function is:

```
function(context):
    if (context in simple form)
        return base case
    else
        simplify context
        call function(simplified context)
        return induction of results
```

The canonical example:

```
int factorial(int n) {
    if (n <= 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
}
```

Or in your case:

```
public static void recursionTest(int num) {
    if (num == 0) {
        System.out.println("base case: " + num);
    } else {
        System.out.println("inductive case: " + num);
        recursionTest(num - 1);
    }
}
```

If you stick strictly to this form you'll find recursion easier to construct and read.

Answer (score 0):

When you use recursive call it creates a stack in the memory. The stack holds the incomplete tasks. Here when the program is executing the code `recursionTest(num - 1);` it is putting the previous task i.e. the rest of the function body inside a stack. 
Something Like this happens:
[image]

Now when the complete stack has been created remove the recursive call from the program and then execute it. You will understand.